# Is there a way to completely disable com_installer in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

They keep injecting code to this component and install their scripts. Is there a way to disable the installation of new extensions in joomla 2.5?

Comment: Who is 'they' and why do they even have access to the admin side of your install?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to rename "com_installer" in backend files under components folder. Don't remove it, you might need it in future.
or you can redirect user to control panel, when they try to access com_installer.

Remove "Extension Manager" from admin menu. 
For that, Go to admin

```
administrator\modules\mod_menu\tmpl\default_enabled.php 
find for "index.php?option=com_installer" Comment MenuItem Creation code
```